# error al insertar fecha y hora automaticamente phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Intento insertar un registro en una de mis tablas de mi base de datos y al insertarlo ese campo de fecha y hora automática me sale todo en cero, el insertar lo hago por medio de php y lo hago de esta manera. El primer "0" es para una llave que es autoincrementable y el segundo "0" es donde va el campo de fecha/hora no se si deba ser así la sintaxis o si deba configurar algo en phpmyadmin para que me lo muestre.

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO tics VALUES( '$n'  , 0 , '$tit', '$con', 0 )";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haber, la estructura de tu tabla, en las columnas de fecha y hora tiene un valor asignado por defecto?, para entender como es que pretendes que se inserten esos valores automáticamente, edita y muestra la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: Hola, podrías poner la estructura de la tabla a donde quieres hacer la inserción y decir en que formato estás tratando de guardar la fecha

Comment: espero la imagen que agregue sirva de algo

Comment: si haces el print de las variables, que traen?

Comment: No sé si eso ha cambiado con el tiempo en mysql pero, ¿no debería omitirse el enviar valores para los campos que tienen DEFAULT? Enviar cero va a poner cero en el campo; otra cosa es que funcione con el campo que autoincrementa el entero...

Comment: si realizo el print me trae puros ceros nada de fecha ni hora

Comment: el poner "0" a la hora de insertar esta bien? si no lo hago no se genera el registro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberías probar hacer la instrucción `INSERT` de la siguiente forma a ver como te va

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tics (idus, tit, con) VALUES ('$idus','$tit','$con')";
```

no hace falta pasarle parámetros a los campos que son automáticos, quizá es eso lo que te esta causando problemas.